# Calculate inputs with same MySQL row id with jquery

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with some data with `Auto_Increment` id.

**Database structure** [image](http://s10.postimg.org/63snyjwkp/Capture.png)

I call all database data with this ***index.php*** file.

```
echo "<form style='width:1500px; backgrond-color:transparent;' action='update.php' method='post' class='form-group'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{  
    $Budget = $row['Budget'];
    $Availed_in_Regions = $row['Availed_in_Regions'];
    $Requested_in_KBL = $row['Requested_in_KBL'];
    $Received_in_KBL = $row['Received_in_KBL'];
    $Availed_in_KBL = $row['Availed_in_KBL'];
    $Balance = $row['Balance'];
    $y_total = $row['y_total'];
    $x_total = $row['x_total'];
echo "<div class='calc_container'> 

<input type='hidden' class='id' name='id[]' value='".$row['ID']."'>

<input type='text' class='budget' name='Budget[]' value='".$row['Budget']."'>

<input type='text' class='avail_region' name='Availed_in_Regions[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_Regions']."'>

<input type='text' class='req_kbl' name='Requested_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Requested_in_KBL']."'>

<input type='text' class='rec_kbl' name='Received_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Received_in_KBL']."'>

<input type='text' class='avail_kbl' name='Availed_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_KBL']."'>

<input type='text' class='balance' name='Balance[]' value='".$row['Balance']."'>

<input type='text' class='x_total' name='x_total[]' value='".$row['x_total']."'>

</div>";


}
```

**My question**
I want to sum all input values with same MySQL row id and show that total sum value in `x_total` input

**like**: every inputs which have MySQL id `[1]` should be summed and total should be written in `x_total[1]`

and every inputs which have MySQL id `[2]` should be summed and total should be written in `x_total[2]`

Answer (score 0):

change sql like this.

```
select sum(y_total),...
```

Comment: Thanks i want to show the sum value at the same page with jquery

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the `$x_total` input needs be a sum of all other fields in the mysql database, we can simply create a variable `$x_total` from adding all other fields together. Then we can use `MySQL UPDATE` to set the total in the database where id = `$row['ID']`.

```
$id = $row['ID'];
$Budget = $row['Budget'];
$Availed_in_Regions = $row['Availed_in_Regions'];
$Requested_in_KBL = $row['Requested_in_KBL'];
$Received_in_KBL = $row['Received_in_KBL'];
$Availed_in_KBL = $row['Availed_in_KBL'];
$Balance = $row['Balance'];

$x_total = $Budget + $Availed_in_Regions + $Requested_in_KBL + $Received_in_KBL + $Availed_in_KBL + $Balance;

$conn->query("UPDATE yourtable SET x_total = $x_total WHERE id = $id");
```

---

We can use the `$x_total` variable in our html input box also with:

`<input type='text' class='x_total' name='x_total[]' value='".$x_total."'>`

Comment: it is not working, i want to sum every inputs which have same MySQL row id

Comment: `$row` will only ever contain a single MySQL row so any calculations you do inside `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` will have the same row id.

Comment: It is working but the total some is not for that row

Comment: Which fields would you like the x_total to be calculated from?

Comment: Thanks, i want to calculate `Budget`, `Availed in Region`, `Request in KBL`, `Received in KBL`, `Availed in KBL` and `Balance` which have id 1 regarding to MySQL database id field  and insert it into `x_total` row of MySQL which have id 1.

Comment: Answer has been edited to include updating the row based on the ID. Remember to put the table name in `yourtable`

Comment: it work good, but i should submit the form twice to change the value in MySQL database

Comment: Glad to hear it's working! If I have helped answer your question, mark it as answered and ask another one. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that that i should refresh the page twice to get the result.